# Php curl Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, curl

Am I missing out anything here? I want to upload to user wall.

```
//Facebook Wall Update
        $params = array('access_token'=>$access_token, 'source'=>'@'.$link, 'message'=>$message);

        $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/". $fbuserid . "/photos?access_token=" . $access_token;

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $graph_url,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Any help for this post?

Answer (score 0):

Few changes -

1. If you want to post to the wall, you should be using the '/feed' endpoint, not '/photos'. That's to post an image into an album (and usually, therefore the timeline).
2. The /feed endpoint does not have 'message'. Instead you can use name, caption, description etc. These are highlighted in the links below.
3. As of February 2013 - you cannot post on any others'  walls except the user who has authenticated the app. Therefore you can only post to 'me/feed'.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

If you were indeed trying to upload a photo, you should try the following array:

```
$msg_body = array(
    'message' => $message,
    'url' => 'http://xyz.com/img.png'
   );
```

If the images are from your own website, replace 'url' with 'source'.

Make sure to have acquired the 'publish_stream' permission from the user.

Comment: Somehow, I am not able to post a picture up with the msg.. can you help?

Comment: If this answer helped, please mark it right with the check mark :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the usage of the Facebook PHP-SDK:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

It has everything you need and a lot of more functions.